# Escape the string for command injection in python?

Tags: python, code-injection

Is it possible in python to form a string variable to escape the concatenation of another, and inject malicious code? The "y" represents admin rights.

Ex:

```
username = request.body.username //this is unsanitized
add("user." + username, "n", timestamp)
```

The username would be: `'name", "y", timestamp)//'`
So the resulting code should look like: `add("user." + "name", "y", timestamp)//,"n",timestamp)`

I tried with single and double quotes, but cant seem to find anything.

Comment: i dont know but maybe you should look up how to add strings in python ?

Comment: No, a variable will not change the code as you have written. Also '//' does not start a comment in Python.

Comment: I know, im working with multiple languages and i sometimes get confused if there is no live codechecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you gonna put that string in `eval` or `exec` there's no point in sanitizing a user input from potential injection attacks. Also use `"".join` to concatenate strings

Comment: This applies only to the Python itself, not if an external command or a DB query is being builit based on that string.